# Adding the numbers in 2 strings together if a different length in C lang?

Tags: c, string

I was trying to find out sum of two strings "999" and "222" and end of the code i found 221 but it should be 1221. I am not sure what i have to do to get the proper output.

```
char a[100], b[100], jogfol[101];
    scanf("%s %s", &a, &b);
    strrev(a);
    strrev(b);
    //printf("%s %s", a, b);
    int i=0, j=0, k=0, hate=0;
   while(i<=strlen(a) && j<=strlen(b))
    {
        int sum = (a[i]-'0')+(b[i]-'0')+hate;
        jogfol[k] = (sum%10+'0');
        hate = sum/10;
        i++; j++; k++;
        //printf("%d %d %d %d %d %s\n", sum, i, j, k, hate, jogfol);
    }
    while(i<strlen(a))
    {
        int sum = (a[i]-'0')+hate;
        jogfol[k] = (sum%10+'0');
        hate = sum/10;
        i++; k++;
        //printf("%d %d %d %d %s\n", sum, i, k, hate, jogfol);
    }
    printf("\n");
    while(j<strlen(b))
    {
        int sum = (b[j]-'0')+hate;
        jogfol[k] = (sum%10+'0');
        hate = sum/10;
        j++; k++;
        //printf("%d %d %d %d %s\n", sum, j, k, hate, jogfol);
    }
```

Comment: After handling all the digits from your input, you must store the carry (your variable `hate`) as well.

Comment: You are adding up from first to last digit. Is that intentional? Normally addition is done starting from least significant digit.

Comment: Any particular reason why you aren't using `strtol`? You can replace all of this with a single `printf("%ld\n", strtol(a,0,10) + strtol(b,0,10) );`

Comment: @Gerhardh Presumably the non-standard `strrev()` calls are reversing the strings in place.

Comment: Why are you using `<= strlen(...)` instead of `< strlen(...)`?

Comment: @IanAbbott you are right. I missed these calls.

Comment: Presumably, the code also calls `strrev(jogfol)` after the code that has been shown?

Answer (score 0):

OP's troubles include not a final reverse, no width limit in `scanf()` and not handling a final carry ("found 221 but it should be 1221").

There really is no need to reverse `a, b`.

---

To "add" *strings*, start from the least significant digit and work to the most significant digits.

- Add digits when `a` and `b` both have digits.
- Add digits when `a` has digits.
- Add digits when `b` has digits.
- Account for a final carry out.

Some untested code to give OP an idea.

```
// a + b --> c
void add_string(size_t n, const char a[n], const b[n], c[n + 1]) {
  size_t a_len = strlen(a);
  size_t b_len = strlen(b);
  size_t c_len = a_len > b_len ? a_len : b_len;
  assert(c_len < n);
  c[c_len] = '\0';
  n = c_len;
  int sum = 0;
  while (a_len > 0 && b_len > 0) {
    sum += a[--a_len] - '0' + b[--b_len] - '0';
    c[--c_len] = sum % 10 + '0';
    sum /= 10;
  }
  while (a_len > 0) {
    sum += a[--a_len] - '0';
    c[--c_len] = sum % 10 + '0';
    sum /= 10;
  }
  while (b_len > 0) {
    sum += b[--b_len] - '0';
    c[--c_len] = sum % 10 + '0';
    sum /= 10;
  }
  if (sum > 0) {
    memmove(c + 1, c, n + 1);
    c[0] = sum + '0';
  }
}
```

---

`char a[100], b[100]; scanf("%s %s", &a, &b);` implies OP is not compiling with all warnings enabled.  Save time, enable them all.

`printf("%d %d %d %d %d %s\n", sum, i, j, k, hate, jogfol);` is a problem as `jogfol[]` is not certainly a *string* as it may lack a *null character*.